# How to reload a image on button click without refreshing the page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

I want to reload the image on a button click without refreshing the page. For now, the image is changing when i click on "Refresh Image" link button. But the PAGE REFRESHES..

Code :

```
                  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptchaInput" BorderStyle="Solid" Style="vertical-align: top" runat="server" Width="106px" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Image ID="img_captcha" runat="server" Height="32px" ImageUrl="~/captchaJPEG.aspx" Width="108px" /> 
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="captcha_refresh" runat="server">Refresh Image</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ContentTemplate> 
                      <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="captcha_refresh" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What am i doing wrong with this code ? I am using asncpostbacktrigger and assigning a control id and event name to it. Which to my knowledge is a correct approach. Please advice.

Comment: why do you have two different update panels? can you move your linkbutton to first update panel?

Comment: its working fine i tried it...

Comment: @rs. I have put all the controls in one update panel. Please see the updated code. But the page still refreshes..!!!

Comment: I tried your code, its working fine!!!

Comment: @MicrosoftPS Is it working for you in IE ? For me it is working only in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Remove Triggers from `UpdatePanel1`, Add Click event handler to `captcha_refresh` Link button. Inside that event call `UpdatePanel1.Update();`

Comment: Tried update of updatepanel1 in my clickevent code and removed the triggers from aspx, but still the page refreshes.

Comment: problem is somewhere else not here??

Comment: Ok now, i fixed an issue in my web.config and now the page is not refreshing. But the image is not changing on my click event of link button. Only if I refresh my page, the image changes. Any idea ?

Comment: One more thing is, the image changes without page load in CHROME. But the image is not changing and there is no page load in IE and FIREFOX while clicking my link button. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Yes i have in my master page which the page uses